# Why rust use rsi to pass parameter to fn pointer

Tags: rust, abi

For normal functions, rust behaves the same as x86-64 abi which pass parameter use register starting with rdi, but for fn pointer rust use rsi, so why do rustc choose to do so?

Take this for an example

```rust
fn foo(f: fn(u64)) {
    f(10);
}

fn main() {
    foo(|i| {
        i + 1;
    });
}
```

the closure is compiled to

```
playground::main::{{closure}}:
    sub rsp, 24
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 8], rdi
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 16], rsi
    add rsi, 1
    setb    al
    test    al, 1
    jne .LBB11_2
    add rsp, 24
    ret
```

and it's using rsi while the normal function `foo` is compiled to

```
playground::foo:
    sub rsp, 24
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 16], rdi
    mov eax, 10
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 8], rdi
    mov rdi, rax
    mov rax, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
    call    rax
    add rsp, 24
    ret
```

which use rdi and calling it in `main` is

```
    lea     rdi, [rip + core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once]
    call    playground::foo
```

so this is done with calling `core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once` which does

```
core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once:
    sub rsp, 40
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 16], rdi
    mov rsi, qword ptr [rsp + 16]
    lea rdi, [rsp + 8]
    call    playground::main::{{closure}}
    jmp .LBB4_1

.LBB4_1:
    jmp .LBB4_2

.LBB4_2:
    add rsp, 40
    ret
```

Comment: A quick [tests](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0fdeec01ad6d3625f02310fe70b19c64) shows that not to be the case (`leaq playground::foo(%rip), %rdi`). Maybe your code is more convoluted than my example?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: @rodrigo you aren't calling the clousure

Comment: `the closure is compiled to` Is there no `ret` in closure? Please post some related assembly context. Or really, just post the whole assembly, it's not that long. `with calling core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once which does` So that function doesn't call anything? It does way more then two assembly isntructions.

Comment: Its definitely passing something in rdi, but it appears to be passing a pointer to uninitialized stack space. Why I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure speculation, but it may be that closures are always compiled as structs with an inherent method which takes &self, and then a wrapper is generated to convert that to function pointer. This would allow the inherent method to also be called as a trait object where a data pointer is passed. The argument to the wrapper is passed in rdi, which then allocates stack space to store a synthesized zero size struct. That wrapper then passes the synthesized struct in rdi, and the parameter in the next parameter slot rsi. In optimized code it would be expected for the inherent method to be inlined into the wrapper, and the weird dance with the registers to synthesize a useless parameter would be eliminated.

In short it is the normal system v calling convention, but there is an extra implicit parameter that is never read, so all the actual parameters get shifted one register further along the list from normal.

Comment: after some [test](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0baf081e7e8db7721b2db51cb24b9ec0) I found your speculation is very persuasive